# Error building APK of Qt application for Android debugging purposes

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, qtandroidextras

I am facing an error very difficult to overcome while deploying my Qt-based application in a physical android device for debugging purposes.

My development environment consists of:

- Qt Creator 8.0.1
- Kit: Android Qt 5.12.5 Clang armeabi-v7a
- JDK: java-8-openjdk-amd64
- Android NDK 19.2.5345600
- Android build platform SDK: android-30 (matching the android version of the physical Android device used for debbuging)

After building the project successfully, the application output showns the following error:

> E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: qtMainLoopThread
> E AndroidRuntime: Process: x.x.x, PID: 32169
> E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libQt5Svg_armeabi-v7a.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~iLirUIB85J_FVJSfM641DA==/x.x.x-3-HqALor76ox7Ss_E3R6nQ==/lib/arm/libQtZint.so in namespace classloader-namespace
> E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:939)
> E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1628)
> E AndroidRuntime:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$3.run(QtNative.java:223)
> E AndroidRuntime:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$2.run(QtThread.java:87)
> E AndroidRuntime:   at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:61)
> E AndroidRuntime:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
> I Process : Sending signal. PID: 32169 SIG: 9

I've already tried different build platform SDKs in the "Build Android APK" Build&Run settings but without success.

I would appreciate any help you could potentially provide on this. Thank you!